# Tensorflow compute update_op for metric using values from previous iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on a custom metric and my `update_op` is a function of current values and the values from the previous run. How do I use them? I have smth like this

```
x, y = f(data)

var1 = metric_variable([], dtypes.float32)
var1_op = state_ops.assign_add(var1, x + y_previous_iteration)

var2 = metric_variable([], dtypes.float32)
var2_op = state_ops.assign_add(var2, y)

value = _aggregate_across_replicas(
            metrics_collections, f2, var1, var2)
update_op = f2(var1_op, var2_op)
```

UPDATED: The way metrics work is that during evaluation at each step variables are getting aggregated. It is done so that at each moment the metric value is the value over all data seen until now and not the value computed over the last batch. For example if you have `var1_op = state_ops.assign_add(var1, x)` it means that at each iteration `var1 = var1_prev + x`. For example, I simplified computation of `auc` [here](https://gist.github.com/ychervonyi/05ee35a70bd5f7751a97bbd6ef1f879d). I need to do `var1 = var1_prev + x + y_prev`.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking... Please be more specific.

Comment: Sorry. I expanded my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The idea is inspired by [`streaming_concat`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/contrib/metrics/python/ops/metric_ops.py#L3561) to create a variable of size `2*size` ( where `size` is the length of `y`), keep data from previous run in the first part of `y` and the new value in second part as `[y_prev, y]`. Here is the code:

```
y_var = metric_variable([2 * size], name='y_var')
        copy_op = y_var[size:].assign(y_var[:size])
        with ops.control_dependencies([copy_op]):
            update_ops['y_var'] = state_ops.assign(y_var[:size], y)
```